# Curiosity with share app android link to google play

Tags: android, google-play

I would to know how can I insert a link on my google app that leads to the google play store showing the application itself.

Let me explain, I still have not posted my application yet and do not have a valid link for the google play, but if I wanted to put in my app a link that leads to market my app how do I do it not having yet published?

Answer (score 3):

Try this function .. Hope it helps :)

```
private void launchMarket() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
    Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
        startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " unable to find market app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link to the Google Play website `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name` or you can use the maket schema: `market://search?q=your.package.name`.

The last one will open the PlayStore in every case (unless you have installed some  malicious apps).

Comment: Also from within an android app `market://details?id=<package_name>`

Comment: Why the downvote? I mean okay I did not add code but this is a general hint how to slove it.